# Oracle materialized view with Entity Framework model

Tags: view, model, frameworks, entity, materialized

Is it possible to query Oracle materialized view with Entity Framework model using linq?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  From the Entity Framework's perspective, a materialized view is a table.  The only caveat is that to generate the model from the materialized view, the materialized view must have a non-nullable column that could be used as the primary key.

Comment: Yes, i'd missed out the primary key issue on MV. Thanks this solves the problem.